# Creating & Configuring a SSL Self signed cert for a IdentityServer3

Tags: identityserver3

FOR DEVELOPMENT:  I configured my site to run without SSL for my development box and it all works great.

Now I am moving this to our dev testing server so I can test it there.
*I first ran it as a non ssl intranet site to confirm configuration and etc....
It works perfectly.*

**Now I am in the process of creating a cert for the site and plan to use *self signed certs* for developer testing.**

I have read many post ( [google search](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=identityServer3%20The%20remote%20certificate%20is%20invalid%20according%20to%20the%20validation%20procedure) )   on the topic related to the error I am getting.

Basically, I am 110% sure I am not creating this cert correctly for the site to which I need to bind it to.

## The error:

**The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.**

So I am trying to understand what they mean by **answers like this**:

*When working with self-signed certificates: add them to the trusted root authorities & use the **hostname** instead of **localhost**. ]
So if your computer name is "mypc", the uri should be "https://mypc/..." instead of "https://localhost/...".*

This is what is confusing to me... 
For example , if computer name is: svr-d-web-003
So the uri:  https: //svr-d-web-003/?????

Looking at the advanced settings Bindings could I extrapolate the uri as:  https: //svr-d-web-003/webhost.oauth.xyz.org  ??  This seems wrong to me... 
Site settings and etc....

Used these steps to create the cert:
1.  C:> certlm.msc
2.  Right-click on Certificates, then click All Tasks/Request New Certificate

3. Click Next, Next
4. Click on link as shown under the template you need.
5. Select Common Name from drop down
6. Enter the machine name dns name (example:  svr-v-wus-001), then click Add button
7. Click OK,
8. In the Requests Certificates window check the box for xyz, click Enroll
9. Look in the certificates store and it’ll be there – you may need to click Refresh button
10. Follow up In IIS – you’ll bind the certificate there to your site. Remember the name needs to match the url.  (This might be my issue here...)

See attachment...
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it to work.
When creating the cert I had to match the name of the cert (common name) to the site.

For example:  the site is https://identService.oauth.xyz.org  so the cert name needed to be  identService.oauth.xyz.org.

Then it all worked.  I was confusing the site name with the machine name.  Doh...